# InvalidValueError: setPov in property zoom: NaN is not an accepted value, using Street view with GoogleMutant

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I'm making a map using Leaflet and the GoogleMutant plugin. I found a problem, which I cannot consistently reproduce.

This is my code for defining the Leaflet map and the GoogleMutant layer:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-23.553390347066472, -46.6274517774582], 18);

var roads = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
  maxZoom: 21,
  streetViewControl: true,
  type: 'roadmap',
}).addTo(map);
```

And this is the code for adding StreetView

```
var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(getUrlParameter('lat'),getUrlParameter('lng'));

var panoEl = document.getElementById('pano');
var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(panoEl, {
    position: fenway,
    pov: { heading: 165, pitch: 0 }
});

roads.on('spawned', function(ev) {
  var googleMap = ev.mapObject;
  googleMap.setOptions({  streetViewControl: true, fullscreenControl: false,})
  googleMap.setStreetView(pano)
});
```

Most of the time it works, but sometimes I get this error:

```
InvalidValueError: setPov in property zoom: NaN is not an accepted value
```

I took a look at the documentation of both StreetView and GoogleMutant but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot have a look at the (closed) source code for GMaps, so I can only *guess* that the problem might be because a `zoom` property somewhere is missing.

One possibility is [`google.maps.StreetViewPanoramaOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#StreetViewPanoramaOptions) - there is a `zoom` property there. So instead of

```
var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(panoEl, {
  position: fenway,
  pov: { heading: 165, pitch: 0 }
});
```

I'd try something like

```
var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(panoEl, {
  position: fenway,
  pov: { heading: 165, pitch: 0 },
  zoom: 0
});
```

The other possibility is that there is a race condition between when the GoogleMutant is being spawned, and when it's changing its zoom level.

If you read the code for GoogleMutant, you'll see that [the `spawned` event happens when the mutant is created](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/blob/5e3b4daef5172df4e4dbdb02d70824b789c8a032/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js#L190), but way before [its zoom level is set](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/blob/5e3b4daef5172df4e4dbdb02d70824b789c8a032/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js#L372). There is a non-trivial sequence of events happening when the mutant is being added to the map.

So to ensure that the mutant's zoom level is initialized before showing the panorama, I'd change...

```
roads.on('spawned', function(ev) {
  var googleMap = ev.mapObject;
  googleMap.setOptions({  streetViewControl: true, fullscreenControl: false,})
  googleMap.setStreetView(pano)
});
```

...into something like...

```
roads.once('spawned', function(ev) {
  roads.once('loading', function(ev) {
    var googleMap = ev.mapObject;
    googleMap.setOptions({  streetViewControl: true, fullscreenControl: false,})
    googleMap.setStreetView(pano)
  });
});
```

If this is the case, another possibility would be to fire a different custom event around [line 79 of GoogleMurant.js](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/blob/5e3b4daef5172df4e4dbdb02d70824b789c8a032/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js#L79) - maybe something like `this.fire('ready')`

Comment: Good afternoon, Ivan, how are you?
I would like to know why I miss this zoom value because if I use console.log (pano.zoom) or console.log (pano.pov) I can see the correct values, however when I make a console.log (pano) soon after comes with invalid values.

to continue using even without bothering with the error I did another function in which set that zom and pov again.

Thanks again for your reply :}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when prototyping an application which used CSS transitions, it turns out that when the StreetViewPanorama is calculating values for the zoom it uses; it takes the height and width of the element into account to choose a better resolution if possible for the street view imagery it seems...

The issue is definitely how the zoom property is calculated by the StreetViewPanorama, the control gets a value `Infinity` calculated for the `pov.zoom` property and somehow that or `NaN` gets passed to the inner function.

You can use the following code to work around the issue: (it overwrites the function and maintains the previous version)

```
 //Hack, use a delay for now because of how zoom is calculated.
        const test = this.pano.setPov.bind(this.pano);
        this.pano.setPov = function () {   
            //debugger; // you can inspect this.pov.zoom here to see Infinity...
            if (this.j) context.clearTimeout(this.j); //this may need to be changed per the version of google maps your using.
            const args = { zoom: arguments[0].zoom | 0 || 1, heading: arguments[0].heading | 0 || 0, pitch: arguments[0].pitch || 0 };
            if (false == isFinite(args.zoom) || args.zoom === 0) args.zoom = 1;
            if (false == isFinite(args.pitch)) args.pitch = 0;
            if (false == isFinite(args.heading)) args.heading = 0;
            setTimeout(function () { test(args); }, 100);   //Fix is here             
        };
```

Google should really improve the `setPov` on the StreetViewPanorama class to ensure the needed parameters are passed and that they have sensible values rather than throwing an error there IMHO.